# Genric Object based query in mongodb

Tags: spring-data, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB and, say want to query the following document:

```
{
  "id":3, 
  "updatedOn" : ISODate("2018-11-22T10:58:48.536Z"),
  "totalMaxScore" : 50,
  "maxAttempts" : 4,
  "sections" : [
      {
       "sectionName" : "coding",
       "maxScore" : 30,
       "concepts" : [
           "css box model"
       ],
       "skills" : [
           "is aware of css syntax"
       ],
       "difficultyLevel" : "easy",
       "weightage" : 48
     }
  ]
```

From Mongo Client I'm able to do: `db.quiz.find({'sections.skills': 'is aware of css syntax'}).pretty()`

But I want to search programatically documents based on skills provided at runtime. I understand I need to use `@Query` but need help on the generic query to write.

Comment: what hvae you tried so far

Comment: `@Query(value = "{ 'sections.skills' : ?0 }")`
 `List<Challenge> findChallengesBySkill(String skill);`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer.

```
@Query(value = "{ 'sections':{$elemMatch:{'skills: {$elemMatch: {$eq: ?0 }}}}})"
List<Challenge> findChallengesBySkill(String skill);
```